# Function raise error with return statement

Tags: r, raster, calc

I want to process a own designed function on every cell using the calc function of the "raster" package.

Everything works perfectly when I try to print the "final" result of the function (value I want to return), but when I try to use return statement, I got an error :

```
Error in .local(x, values, ...) : 
  values must be numeric, integer or logical.
```

Here is the code leading to that error

```
inR <- 'D://test/TS_combined_clipped.tif'
outR <- 'D://test/R_test3.tif'

rasterB <- brick(inR)
fun1 <-function(x){
  years = seq(1, 345)
  na_idx = which(is.na(x))
  years = years[-na_idx]
  x <- na.omit(x)
  idx = detectChangePoint(x, cpmType='Student', ARL0=500)$changePoint
  return(years[idx]) # this raises error
  # print(years[idx]) # This does *not* raises any error
}

r <- calc(rasterB, fun=fun1, filename=outR, overwrite=TRUE)
```

How is it possible to have a return statement to make it fails ?

Some of my tests leads to the fact that it seems that the process fails just after the execution of the calc function on the very last cell of the rasterBrick.
But I have no clue of where to start to try to fix this.

[Input image is available here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cND3NO3EA3HPSyJocN16uvlBIC5tWueW/view?usp=sharing)

**[EDIT]**

I just noticed that if I use `return(idx)` instead of  `return(year[idx])` the process works without error raised.
So it seems that the problem is more at fetching the value of the year variable.
Is therefore any particular thing that I missed in the use of indexes with R ?

Comment: Likely there are cases where no change point is detected.  Then `idx` will be zero, and `years[idx]` will be a length zero vector.  Apparently `calc()` doesn't like the length zero vector.  Or perhaps the issue is that more than one change point is detected.  We don't have your data, and can't tell.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll check your suggestions, and there is a link to the input data (end of the post, Before the "edit")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment of  user2554330 put me on the good track, issue was that calc cannot handle a "numeric(0)" result.

Updated code is then

```
inR <- 'D://test/TS_combined_clipped.tif'
outR <- 'D://test/R_test3.tif'

rasterB <- brick(inR)
fun1 <-function(x){
  years = seq(1, 345)
  na_idx = which(is.na(x))
  years = years[-na_idx]
  x <- na.omit(x)
  idx = detectChangePoint(x, cpmType='Student', ARL0=500)$changePoint
  if (idx==0){
    return(0)
  } else {
    return(as.integer(years[idx]))
  }
}

r <- calc(rasterB, fun=fun1, filename=outR, overwrite=TRUE)
```